# Asignar la data http en ionic 2 al cargar la vista

Tags: ionic, http, angularjs-2.0

No puedo entender por qué no asigna el valor a la variable `this.userProfile` probé con promesas y tampoco asigna, alguna idea?

Código:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import * as localforage from "localforage";

import { ProfileServices } from '../../providers/profile.services';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    providers: [ProfileServices]
})
export class Profile {

    public user: any;
    public userProfile: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private profile: ProfileServices, public params: NavParams, public storage: Storage, public loading: LoadingController) {
        this.getPerfilData();
        console.log("user profile" + this.userProfile); //Undefined ?       
    }

    getPerfilData() {
        this.presentLoadingDefault();

        this.storage.get('user').then((user) => {

            this.user = JSON.parse(user);

            this.profile.getProfile("token", this.user.idUser).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.userProfile = data;
                    console.log("user profile" + this.userProfile); //Aqui me retorna la Data http success                   
                });

        });
    }

    presentLoadingDefault() {
        let loading = this.loading.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });
        loading.present();
        setTimeout(() => {
            loading.dismiss();
        }, 2000);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        // this.getPerfilData();
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        // this.getPerfilData();        
    }
}
```

---

Gist: https://gist.github.com/vanckruz/92d6ea6ac114e6d28e88eb22caddc82a

Comment: imprimiste el valor de `data` ?

Comment: Si dentro del getPerfilData hago un console.log y me trae la data perfecto pero se la estoy asignando y no persiste fuera del metodo pierde el valor como se ve en el constructor me arroja undefined

Comment: Estoy usando navegación por pestañas de ionic 2, la idea es cuando haga click en una pestaña cargue la data para yo mostrarla en la vista pero me arroja undefined la variable que mostrare en la vista.

Comment: La llamada http la hago normal como esta en la doc de angular 2, en el servicio hago un .get(ruta).map(res => res.json())

Comment: Puedes modificar `(data) =>` por `data =>`

Comment: yo lo tenia asi: data => this.userProfile = data , la cuestión es que afuera del método no persiste el valor asignado no se si es el storage que hace conflicto?

Comment: Es que afuera del storage no agarra el parametro que suelta el storage, incluso le puse parametro de prueba directamente en el constructor y tampoco asigno: en el contructor puse directo esto:             this.profile.getProfile("token", this.user.idUser).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.userProfile = data;
                    console.log("user profile" + this.userProfile); //Aqui me retorna la Data http success                   
                }); al hacer log a this.userProfile de nuevo en el contructor me da undefined :/

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas recomendable es usar promesas para tratar tus problemas de asignación

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import * as localforage from "localforage";

import { ProfileServices } from '../../providers/profile.services';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    providers: [ProfileServices]
})
export class Profile {

  public user: any;
  public userProfile: any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public profile: ProfileServices, 
              public params: NavParams, 
              public storage: Storage, 
              public loading: LoadingController) {
   // Solo usar para asignar variables
}

ngOnInit(){

    let loading = this.loading.create({
        content: 'Please wait...'
    });
    // Mostramos el loading
    loading.present();

    this.getPerfilData().then( (data) => {
        // Cuando la promesa termine cerramos el loading
        loading.dismiss();
        this.userProfile = data;

    }).catch( (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        // Si ocurre un error tambien cerramos el loading
        loading.dismiss();
    });

}

getPerfilData(): Promise<any>{

  return new Promise( (resolve,reject) => { 

    this.storage.get('user').then( (user) => {

        try{
          // Parsear json siempre es conveniente try-catch
          this.user = JSON.parse(user);

          this.profile.getProfile("token", this.user.idUser).subscribe(
          (data) => {
              // Retornamos
              resolve(data);           
          }, (error) => {
              reject(error);
          });

        }catch(error){
            reject(error);
        }

    },(error) => {
        reject(error);
    });

  });

}

ionViewDidLoad() {
    // this.getPerfilData();
}

ionViewWillEnter() {
    // this.getPerfilData();        
}
}
```

profile.html

Se puede validar con "?", si userProfile esta undefined no nos arrojará error cuando preguntemos por sus atributos

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
    <div class="image_center" *ngIf="userProfile?.picUser">         
        <img [src]="userProfile.picUser">    
    </div>
    <ion-card-content *ngIf="userProfile?.firstName && userProfile?.lastName">
        <h1>{{ userProfile.firstName }} {{ userProfile.lastName }}</h1>         
        <div class="header_primary">
            Interest
        </div>
    </ion-card-content> 
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: @JhonnyVancKruz preguntó porque no le resulta su código. Aparte de compartir lo que (se supone) es una solución, podrías explicar un poco que había que cambiar? Así la respuesta tiene un valor para mas publico.

Comment: @StefanNolde tienes toda la razón, mi error

Answer (score 0):

@Jhonny Vanckruz, no estás *perdiendo* el valor fuera del metodo, es que el metodo no se ha ejecutado cuando haces el primer `console.log` entonces el valor no existe todavía. No debes tratar de acceder a variables que reciben sus valores dentro de promesas o observadores fuera de esas promesas o observadores, porque no se sabe cuando se va a cumplir la promesa.  Mas bien, debes refactorizar tu código para que se use en el mismo metodo de promise o obervador.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import * as localforage from "localforage";

import { ProfileServices } from '../../providers/profile.services';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-profile',
    templateUrl: 'profile.html',
    providers: [ProfileServices]
})
export class Profile {

    public user: any;
    public userProfile: any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private profile: ProfileServices, public params: NavParams, public storage: Storage, public loading: LoadingController) {
        this.getPerfilData();
        console.log("user profile" + this.userProfile); // No se ha cumplido el código dentro del observador      
    }

    getPerfilData() {
        this.presentLoadingDefault();

        this.storage.get('user').then((user) => {

            this.user = JSON.parse(user);

            this.profile.getProfile("token", this.user.idUser).subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    this.userProfile = data;
                    console.log("user profile" + this.userProfile); //Aqui sí se ha cumplido y puedes accederlo.                  
                });

        });
    }

    presentLoadingDefault() {
        let loading = this.loading.create({
            content: 'Please wait...'
        });
        loading.present();
        setTimeout(() => {
            loading.dismiss();
        }, 2000);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        // this.getPerfilData();
    }

    ionViewWillEnter() {
        // this.getPerfilData();        
    }
}
```

y para mostrarlo en tu vista:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
    <ion-card>
        <div class="image_center">          
            <img [src]="userProfile.picUser">    
        </div>
        <ion-card-content *ngIf="userProfile !== undefined && userProfile !== null">
            <h1>{{ userProfile.firstName }} {{ userProfile.lastName }}</h1>         
            <div class="header_primary">
                Interest
            </div>
        </ion-card-content> 
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Si pero necesito la variable para recorrerla en la vista, en la consola me da error de desconocido idUser de undefined ..en este caso yo quiero mostar en la vista el detalle del usuario {{ userProfile.nombre }} -> pero userProfile es undefined

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar también el código de la vista?

Comment: la vista es esta: 
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>
 <ion-card>
  <div class="image_center">   
   <img [src]="userProfile.picUser">    
  </div>
  <ion-card-content *ngIf="userProfile != undefined || userProfile != null  ">
   <h1>{{ userProfile.firstName }} {{ userProfile.lastName }}</h1>
   <h2 *ngIf="userProfile.isDriverRole">Driver</h2>
   <div class="header_primary">
    Interest
   </div>
  </ion-card-content> 
 </ion-card>
</ion-content>

Comment: Este es el gist de la vista: https://gist.github.com/vanckruz/a6ec505d5ad07fbdfee3e999018485ca

Comment: Aquí es el problema: `*ngIf="userProfile != undefined || userProfile != null"`.  En ese caso debes usar `&&` en vez de `||` porque si `userProfile = ==undefined` entonces `userProfile !== null` y todavía va a mostrarlo.

Comment: También, este no tiene mucho que ver con tu problema, es un consejo nada mas, pero siempre debes usar `!==` en vez de `!=` y también `===` en vez de `==`.